# Can i scrape twitter post image directly from a page using a GET request?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, twitter, get

## Can i scrape twitter image directly from HTML?

The answer is no, or at least according to my attempt it wasn’t

```py
import requests

# The URL for the GET request
url = '<twitter post link here'>
# Perform the GET request
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:

    # save the html content into a variable
    response = response.text
    print(response)

    with open("my_file.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        # write the string into the file
        f.write(response)

else:
    print(f'Failed to get URL. Status code: {response.status_code}')
```

I wrote Python code that required no dependency, despite requests.
Then this code uses Python's built-in feature called `open`, which permits the creation and download of an HTML file. The script would make a GET call to a Twitter post.

The problem is what it does is return an empty Twitter page, with only the Twitter logo available.

That happens probably because it is in a modal?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Twitter (x.com) doesn't directly return the web page with the image or the original post. They use JavaScript to load the actual web page afterwards.
Twitter tries to prevent you from scraping the page via simple requests, because they offer a paid API. The API allows developers to easily access the content.
Even if you got the actual web page, it would not contain any images. The html document only points to the address of the image.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to download images from websites dynamically rendered by javascript using the requests module unless you use some sort of API provided by the website. However, you could use Selenium to open a browser and render the HTML code.

The code below will download the picture from an example twitter post if you've set up Selenium properly.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

#file to save
picture_filename = 'my_picture.png'

#open firefox browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#open url
driver.get('https://twitter.com/WagnerRM/status/1697373778114715742/photo/1')

#wait enough time for page to render
time.sleep(10)

#using beautiful soup to find the image we want
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
images = soup.find_all('img')

images = [img['src'] for img in images if '/media/' in img['src']]
for image in images:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, picture_filename)
```

PS:

To open the browser you first need to install the webdriver for it. The code above uses Firefox. If you're using Windows for example, you can use the code below.

```
pip install webdrivermanager
webdrivermanager firefox --linkpath ./
```

This will download a file named geckodriver.exe to your current path which is used to open the browser.